# navigationOptions does not show my button on header

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm using this navigation library:

`react-navigation`

I want to add an Icon to right of header.

```
export default class KasianServices extends Component {

  static navigationOptions = {
    headerRight: {
            right: <Button title="Save" />
        }
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: colorConstants.ONE_APP_COLOR,

    },

  };
```

`heaerStyle` work fine but my Button doesn't show anything.

Comment: what do you mean by this "my Button doesn't show anything", your button is not being displayed on header or its doing nothing on press?

Comment: my button doesn't appear on the header.

Comment: simply do this
headerRight: (
       <Button title="Save" />
      )
remove "right:"

Comment: did this answer work for you?

Comment: No it does not work